# Fancybox 2 working on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, fancybox-2

I am trying to get fancybox2 to work on mobile devices. It works perfect on desktop.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".fancybox").fancybox();
   });
</script>

<a href="/uploads/test.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="group#" title="text">
   <img src="/uploads/small/test.jpg" />
</a>
```

Any idea what the problem might be? Because I'm out off ideas!

EDIT: Stupid me, another jquery was being loaded when on mobile. Friday-brain had me beat!

Comment: on which mobile browsers does it not work? please provide some more info about browser, browser version, mobile operating system ...

Comment: I've tried on iPhone 4 and 5. Both the actual phones and using the dev tools in chrome to emulate iOS user agents. Fancybox doesn't work in either.

Comment: when you have emulated in Chrome, was there something in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' b-pianot-uudet-38:20
(anonymous function) b-pianot-uudet-38:20
c jquery-latest.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery-latest.js:3160
x.extend.ready jquery-latest.js:433
q

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=has+no+method+'fancybox'&oq=has+no+method+'fancybox'&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.307j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8    we need some more info, maybe it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070979/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-fancybox

Comment: @user2798551 what version of fancybox? ...specifically 2.x.x?

Answer (score -1):

This 'might' actually be a good thing.  Scripts specifically for mobile, like PhotoSwipe have recently been updated so they only run on mobile and leave the desktop without any image handling.  PhotoSwipe is a more mobile native feeling script that runs on iOS Android and many others.  While I know this doesn't really answer your specific question, it may be a great opportunity to maintain your desktop experience and improve your mobile experience at the same time.  If you're curious you can check out Photoswipe here: www.photoswipe.com.

Hope that helps.  :-)
Note: I'm not affiliated with PhotoSwipe in any way.  There are other options.  This is just the one I use.